# How to handle factors related to the exposure but not the outcome

Tags: interaction, dag, adjustment

For example, the postprandial time significantly influences blood glucose levels, with higher levels observed when the postprandial time is short.

Elevated blood glucose is a risk factor for stroke, and increased blood glucose levels are predictive of stroke risk. However, high postprandial blood glucose (only resulting from dietary-induced increases) does not predict the risk of stroke. Whereas sustained postprandial hyperglycemia predicts the risk of stroke (resulting from metabolic abnormality). That means the association between blood glucose and stroke is different in different postprandial time. In a statistical model, how should this phenomenon be dealt with?

`Surv(py, events) ~ glucose + postprandial time`: I am uncertain whether including postprandial time in the model is a good idea, as postprandial time is not associated with the risk of stroke (They should not be associated).

`Surv(py, events) ~ glucose * postprandial time`: The interaction term seems reasonable, but it still treats postprandial time as a predictive factor. Additionally, some individuals concerned about blood glucose might be inclined to extend fasting time (to achieve lower fasting blood glucose levels), while others do not mind. But we cannot isolate this difference because of lack of data. So, I prefer to focus only on the effect of postprandial time on blood glucose (because it is the main effect)

From a DAG perspective, factors simultaneously pointing to exposure and outcome are confounders, while factors pointing only towards the outcome are competing factors; both need adjustment. However, what should be done with factors pointing only towards exposure?

Do factors related to the exposure but not the outcome also need adjustment? If adjusted, how should the interpretation be approached?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'exposure' and 'outcome'? Like exposure as in exposure to a risk factor like 'elevated blood glucose'? And 'after eating time' increases this exposure but does not increase the (risk of the) outcome 'stroke'

Comment: There should be a strong design that is designed to evaluate the time course of eating and glucose. For example, each subject's blood glucose could be measure each hour for several hours after eating. The specific design and knowledge of the time pattern would affect the analysis used.

Comment: Agreed, David. However, research what I am doing is an observational study design, and no interventions have been made regarding the timing of blood collection and diet. It does make me have to handle this data with caution. I'm concerned about making mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about DAGs, but you ask:

> That means the association between blood glucose and stroke is
> different in different postprandial time. In a statistical model, how
> should this phenomenon be dealt with?

This is an example of an interaction. By far the most common way of dealing with it is to add the product of the two variables to the model. Here, though, you might want a spline of postprandial time (and use that spline in the product) because it seems likely that there are nonlinear relationships.

> I am uncertain whether including postprandial time in the model is a
> good idea, as postprandial time is not associated with the risk of
> stroke (They should not be associated).

But being associated with the dependent variable (stroke) is only one reason to include a variable in a model. There are others, like being a necessary control variable, which seems the case here.

You discuss interaction a bit later in your question, but say that you don't want to do it because it still treats postprandial time as predictive. No. Not necessarily.

I'm not sure what extended fasting time has to do with this, but, isn't it captured by postprandial time?

Comment: Yes, I’m actually fitting the model using interactions and lines. My expression was unclear; my mistake. The sample is purely observational; we don't intervene in participants' blood test times or whether they're fasting. Postprandial time (fasting time) is a random variable (it might not be truly random; I assume randomness here), depending on participants' daily schedules and unrelated to stroke risk factors but affecting glucose levels.

Comment: My concern is when I deal with an interaction involving a random variable like postprandial time seems odd. Adjusting variables makes sense, but inserting a random variable in the predictive model gives me pause. As you mentioned, it’s obversely an interaction. I dealt with it as interaction. but what I actually want  is  glucose + time/glucose interaction. However, multiplication yields three coefficients: glucose, time, and time/glucose interaction, making me uncertain if I did right thing.

Comment: So, my understanding is not accurate enough? To add a bit more, my research is observational cohort study. One feature is not requiring fasting blood samples. We believe that blood collection at any time is sufficient for assessing cardiovascular risk in the primary prediction. Thank you for your patient response.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have such concern about a random effect being in an interaction.  But, yes, an interaction will yield three coefficients, just as you found. That's normal.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a semantic issue.

Example: When it is raining then I risk getting wet. When it is raining and I have an umbrella then I don't risk getting wet.

The umbrella is not a risk factor for getting wet. But it does have a relationship with the risk. So yes, you should add it in some way as an interaction.

---

If you have some variable E that correlates positively with a certain risk/outcome O, and another variable X positively correlated with E but not with O, then there can be two reasons.

- The effect of X is to increase E but it has also an effect of decreasing O to such an extent that the effect of the increase E on O is countered.

  Example: The force on an object has an influence on the acceleration of the object. Increasing the weight of an object influences the gravitational force exerted on an object, but not the acceleration and falling speed. (Like [Galileo's experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment)
- The relationship between E and O is not a direct causal relationship. Either O causes E or they may have a common cause.

  Example. Metabolic disease results in an elevated body mass index. This doesn't make that elevated body mass index causes metabolic disease, like training in a gym and acquiring body mass increases the risk of metabolic disease.

In your example with blood glucose levels the situation is also tricky to define what exactly an elevated level is and when it is a risk. It might be that only certain types of elevated levels are risky (like above some trigger level or elevated levels for prolonged times). Too much H20 can kill you, but that doesn't mean that every increase is a risk. So a parameter X that increases E might not neccesarily need to lead to increased outcome O, because the increased exposure E is not a problem.

Blood glucose has natural variations and the higher levels are not neccesarily 'exposure' that is risky. Or even when it might be risky because of some direct causal mechanism, like the sugar damaging the veins and causing stress and complications, then in a setting where we perform some sort of regression we are more interested in glucose concentration differences between people than within people. For example it is the fasting blood glucose levels that might be dangerous. Or it is blood glucose levels above some level that might be dangerous, but below the level changes have no effect. Or the postprandial levels are only a risk when they are high for a long time and surpasses some buffer in protection systems against elevated sugar (like running a long time will  deplete energy and oxygen stores and causes cramps, but normal activity doesn't do this).

Comment: "exposure" refers to a certain situation（ the independent variable）.  Since I do observational research, I prefer to call it "exposure." I understand what you're saying, but I'm a bit uncertain. In my case, fasting time is a random variable. I'm not sure if including it as interaction is appropriate. So I asked it.

Comment: Additionally, I'm unsure if I correctly grasped your words, but I don't agree that a specific level holds any decisive significance in medical research. I don't use thresholds (like diabetes diagnostic thresholds) because even below a threshold, fluctuations in blood glucose or normal high values still indicate risk. Individual variations are equally important and don't become unimportant due to it is lower than a specific level (your exercise example is correct but not applicable universally).